# Android: TextChangedListener issue

Tags: android

I have a edit text and a listview with all contacts .when i search for the name and it displayes the result, As i type in the name it shows the result like AutoComplete, below is my code

```
final EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtContName);

    editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            inputName = s.toString();
            if(inputName!=null&&!inputName.trim().equals("")){

                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search);

            Log.d(TAG, "LoadMoreEntries --> Constants.loadEntries : "
                    + Constants.loadEntries);
            try {
                if (Constants.loadEntries != null) {
                    Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Loading Data-------------------------------", e);
            }
            Constants.loadEntries = new LoadEntries();
            Constants.loadEntries.execute();
        }
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }
    });
```

i am facing issue when i am trying to clear the edittext ,All the results should be displayed when the edit text is clear but it is  not happening. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I change the code for better formatting. This should solve you're problem. I don't know what 
Constants.loadEntries = new LoadEntries(); 
and
Constants.loadEntries.execute();

do, but maybe there can be something wrong too. But try it like the code below:

```
    final EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtContName);

    editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after)
        {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            inputName = s.toString();
            if (inputName != null && !inputName.trim().equals(""))
            {

                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search);

                Log.d(TAG, "LoadMoreEntries --> Constants.loadEntries : "
                        + Constants.loadEntries);
                try
                {
                    if (Constants.loadEntries != null)
                    {
                        Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Loading Data-------------------------------", e);
                }
                Constants.loadEntries = new LoadEntries();
                Constants.loadEntries.execute();
            }
            //Here do the else and call the LoadEntries
            else
            {
                Constants.loadEntries = new LoadEntries();
                Constants.loadEntries.execute();
            }
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count)
        {

        }
    });
```

Better code formatting will definitely help you.

Comment: OK, I changed the code for better formatting and added the solution try the above code.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not getting all of the results when the input is blank?

```
if(inputName!=null&&!inputName.trim().equals("")){
...
}
```